# Setting Windows language to English (United Kingdom) using Ansible

Tags: ansible, azure-vm

I am trying to change the Windows Server display language to English (United Kingdom) from Default English (United states)on an Azure vm.  I installed the language pack using  lpksetup.exe  but  not sure hw to change  display language  using  ansible . Do we  have any ansible  windows modules to do that  or  any other  way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Ansible Code for installing  Language Pack for windows servers

- name: Download Language Pack
  win_get_url:
    url: "{{ repourl }}{{ regionCABFile }}"
    dest: "{{ localregionCABFile }}"
  
- name: Install Language Pack
  win_shell: "lpksetup.exe /i  '{{ regionlocale }}' /p '{{ localregionCABFile }}'  /s /r"

- name: Add Language List
  win_shell: |
    Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList "{{ regionlocale }}" –Force

- name: Set the GeoID and unicode language to English Great Britain
  win_region:
    format: "{{ regionlocale }}"
    location: "{{ regionlocaleid }}"
    unicode_language: "{{ regionunicodelang }}"
  register: result

- name: Restart VM 
  win_reboot:
    when: result.restart_required
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the unicode language to English Great Britain, reboot if required

```
- name: Set the unicode language to English Great Britain, reboot if required
  community.windows.win_region:
    unicode_language: en-GB
  register: result
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_region_module.html